# how to get id exactly value .Why show different Id values? using laravel 9

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-9

Id value different show . Database show like 120230829110713178162 but when get 9223372036854775807.

database
[image]
Query

```
  return Invoice::select('id','customer_account_id','id as mid')->where('customer_account_id', $id)
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->whereIn('status', ['U', 'C'])->get();
```

[image]

Comment: The ID column datatype?

Comment: Can you print the query by replacing `get()` with `dd()`.Also, Id column is the primary key right? 
Can you share Invoice model class?

Comment: I need to ask what this ID is?  Whats the datatype? Why do you use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `9223372036854775807` number looks like [maximum integer value](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_numbers.asp) for PHP in 64-bits systems.

By default Eloquent assumes your primary key is integer so it will cast value from DB to integer so in this case value will be truncated.

You can however set

```php
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

on your `Invoice` model to have this fields as string.

However you should be aware of possible side effects. Depending on your needs you might for example need to set also `$incrementing` property to false and implement some custom logic if needed.

See [primary keys](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#primary-keys) section in Laravel docs.